# ASP C# Repeater Button Not Passing String to Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that creates buttons from selected items on a checkboxlist.  The checkboxlist is a list of item codes.

The buttons appear properly and have the item codes as their text. That works.

On click, the button should call a method using the item code of the button to call a method that populates data to the page, but that is not happening.  I believe the button is passing an empty value.

How do I get the repeater button click to pass the correct value? The method works with  a regular text box, but I have not been able to get it to work with the repeater buttons.

> ASPX

```
  ` <div style="width: 98%; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptItemButtons"
                runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnItemButton"
                    runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'

                     CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'  
                   CommandName="repeater_ItemCommand"
                     />

            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
  </div>`
```

> C#

```
 public void repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    { 
    SaveUserInputsAction();                                                           
    SaveDataAction();
    lblTestMessage.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     GetItemDetails(e.CommandArgument.ToString());           GetCostFactors(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to use `Container.ItemIndex` as a `CommandArgument` instead of `Container.DataItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `OnItemCommand` property of the `Repeater`:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItemButtons" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnItemButton" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'
        />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void Repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{ 
    SaveUserInputsAction();                                                           
    SaveDataAction();
    lblTestMessage.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    GetItemDetails(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    GetCostFactors(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT** After reviewing your code again, I noticed that you are specifying `CommandName="repeater_ItemCommand"` on your button.  It may actually work if you change that to `OnCommand="repeater_ItemCommand"`.  I kind of like specifying the event handler on the `Repeater` but it may come down to personal preference.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks @dana, you are the best, I really appreciate it.